# Ошибка при запуске приложения с OpenGL: execution of module OpenGL_accelerate.numpy_formathandler raised unreported exception

Tags: python, opengl, glfw

Сам код

```py
import glfw
import OpenGL.GL as gl

import imgui
from imgui.integrations.glfw import GlfwRenderer
import menu

def main():
    imgui.create_context()
    window = impl_glfw_init()
    impl = GlfwRenderer(window)

    while not glfw.window_should_close(window):
        glfw.poll_events()
        impl.process_inputs()

        imgui.push_style_var(imgui.STYLE_WINDOW_ROUNDING, 0.0)
        imgui.core.style_colors_light()

        imgui.new_frame()

        menu.menu()

        gl.glClearColor(0.3, 0.3, 0.3, 0.3)
        gl.glClear(gl.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT)

        imgui.render()
        impl.render(imgui.get_draw_data())
        glfw.swap_buffers(window)

    impl.shutdown()
    glfw.terminate()


def impl_glfw_init():
    if not glfw.init():
        print("not initialize OpenGL context")
        exit(1)

    glfw.window_hint(glfw.CONTEXT_VERSION_MAJOR, 3)
    glfw.window_hint(glfw.CONTEXT_VERSION_MINOR, 3)
    glfw.window_hint(glfw.OPENGL_PROFILE, glfw.OPENGL_CORE_PROFILE)

    glfw.window_hint(glfw.OPENGL_FORWARD_COMPAT, gl.GL_TRUE)

    window = glfw.create_window(
        int(1280), int(720), "Application", None, None
    )
    glfw.make_context_current(window)

    if not window:
        glfw.terminate()
        print("not initialize Window")
        exit(1)

    return window

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Ошибка

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\Acer\Desktop\PyImgui project\main.py", line 62, in <module>
    main()
  File "c:\Users\Acer\Desktop\PyImgui project\main.py", line 13, in main
    impl = GlfwRenderer(window)
  File "C:\Users\Acer\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\imgui\integrations\glfw.py", line 12, in __init__
    super(GlfwRenderer, self).__init__()
  File "C:\Users\Acer\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\imgui\integrations\opengl.py", line 60, 
in __init__
    super(ProgrammablePipelineRenderer, self).__init__()
  File "C:\Users\Acer\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\imgui\integrations\base.py", line 17, in __init__
    self._create_device_objects()
  File "C:\Users\Acer\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\imgui\integrations\opengl.py", line 84, 
in _create_device_objects
    last_texture = gl.glGetIntegerv(gl.GL_TEXTURE_BINDING_2D)
  File "src/latebind.pyx", line 39, in OpenGL_accelerate.latebind.LateBind.__call__
  File "src/wrapper.pyx", line 303, in OpenGL_accelerate.wrapper.Wrapper.__call__
  File "src/wrapper.pyx", line 88, in OpenGL_accelerate.wrapper.CArgCalculator.c_call
  File "src/wrapper.pyx", line 69, in OpenGL_accelerate.wrapper.CArgCalculatorElement.c_call
  File "src/wrapper.pyx", line 64, in OpenGL_accelerate.wrapper.CArgCalculatorElement.c_call
  File "src/arraydatatype.pyx", line 355, in OpenGL_accelerate.arraydatatype.SizedOutputOrInput.c_call
  File "src/arraydatatype.pyx", line 224, in OpenGL_accelerate.arraydatatype.ArrayDatatype.c_zeros
  File "src/arraydatatype.pyx", line 69, in OpenGL_accelerate.arraydatatype.HandlerRegistry.c_get_output_handler        
  File "src/arraydatatype.pyx", line 80, in OpenGL_accelerate.arraydatatype.HandlerRegistry.c_handler_by_plugin_name    
  File "C:\Users\Acer\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\OpenGL\plugins.py", line 18, in load    
    return importByName( self.import_path )
  File "C:\Users\Acer\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\OpenGL\plugins.py", line 45, in importByName
    module = __import__( ".".join(moduleName), {}, {}, moduleName)
  File "C:\Users\Acer\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\OpenGL\arrays\numpymodule.py", line 28, 
in <module>
    from OpenGL_accelerate.numpy_formathandler import NumpyHandler
SystemError: ('execution of module OpenGL_accelerate.numpy_formathandler raised unreported exception', 1, <OpenGL.platform.baseplatform.glGetIntegerv object at 0x000002BB0898EB00>)
```